# magento2 Form Validation and FileUpload Plugin not working

Tags: magento2, form-validation, file-upload

i am trying to upload file and it work fine, but form validation is not working when i add file upload JQuery code

NOTE: below All code in same file(test.phtml)

```
<form name="questionnaire_form" id="questionnaire_form" action="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() . 'questionnaire/index/sendEmail'; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="std">
    <div class="product-info-block about-content">
        <div class="page-title category-title">
            <h1><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Custom Design Services FORM')) ?></h1>
        </div>
        <p>                
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Help us understand your requirements better. Fill in this short form, or just email your details to')) ?>
            <a href="mailto:design@xyz.net">design@xyz.net</a>
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__(', and let us know if we can call you to ask clarifying questions.')) ?>
        </p>
        <div class="user-detail">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('First and Last Name')) ?><em>*</em></label>
                    <input name="name" value="<?php
                    if ($name)
                    {
                        echo $name;
                    }
                    ?>" type="text" class="input-text required-entry" tabindex="1">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('User ID / Email')) ?><em>*</em></label>
                    <input name="email" value="<?php
                    if ($email)
                    {
                        echo $email;
                    }
                    ?>" type="text" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" tabindex="2">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone (optional)')) ?></label>
                    <input name="phone" value="<?php
                    if ($phone)
                    {
                        echo $phone;
                    }
                    ?>" type="text" class="input-text validate-digits" tabindex="3">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="blank-label">&nbsp;</label>
                    <ul class="radio-listing">
                        <li tabindex="4">
                            <input type="radio" class="icheck" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Call me')) ?>" name="call_flag" checked="">
                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Call me')) ?></span>
                        </li>
                        <li tabindex="5">
                            <input type="radio" class="icheck" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Do not call me')) ?>" name="call_flag">
                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Do not call me')) ?></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="user-detail">
            <h4><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Fill to the best of your knowledge - no field is mandatory')) ?></h4>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Number of Slides to be designed')) ?></label>
                    <input name="number_of_slides" value="<?php
                    if ($number_of_slides)
                    {
                        echo $number_of_slides;
                    }
                    ?>" type="text" class="input-text" tabindex="6">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Describe Your Style Requirement')) ?> 
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('1. Stylish and Graphical ')) ?>
                            <em>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" tabindex="-1">?
                                    <span>
                                        <ul class="list">
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Consistent 3-5 Colors throughout')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Text in text boxes with shadows/layers etc')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Greater graphical content')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Example Audience - Company Employees, Team Members,Professors and Students, Prospective Customers')) ?></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </em>
                        </span>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('2. Elegant and Simple ')) ?>
                            <em>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" tabindex="-1">?
                                    <span>
                                        <ul class="list">
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Consistent 2-3 Colors throughout')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Corporate Style')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Convey ideas graphically but to a degree')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Example Audience - Board of Directors, CEOs, CFOs, Investors, Investment Banking, Highly Business Oriented Audience')) ?></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </em>
                        </span>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('3. Informal and Playful ')) ?>
                            <em>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" tabindex="-1">?
                                    <span>
                                        <ul class="list">
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Colorful but consistent themes/shades')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Fancy Graphics - visually appealing')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Example Audience - Community gatherings, Schools, Family gatherings and Parties, Churches and Religious gatherings')) ?></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </em>
                        </span>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('4. Combination of the above')) ?> </span>
                    </label>
                    <textarea name="style_option" class="input-text" tabindex="7"><?php
                        if ($style_option)
                        {
                            echo $style_option;
                        }
                        ?></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('URLs or Names of any preferred Slide')) ?> 
                        <a href=""><u><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Templates')) ?></u></a> <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('or')) ?> <a href=""><u><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Diagrams')) ?></u></a><span><a style="color: #393939" href=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Templates are')) ?></a> <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('slide backgrounds')) ?><br><a style="color: #393939" href=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Diagrams are')) ?></a> <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('actual slides')) ?></span>
                    </label>
                    <textarea name="template_or_diagram_details" class="input-text" tabindex="8"><?php
                        if ($template_or_diagram_details)
                        {
                            echo $template_or_diagram_details;
                        }
                        ?></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Description and Flow')) ?><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Notes to the designer. Be as complete and detailed as you can.')) ?></span></label>
                    <textarea class="input-text" name="description" tabindex="9"><?php
                        if ($description)
                        {
                            echo $description;
                        }
                        ?></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="custom_row">
                        <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Upload Files')) ?> <br> <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please upload any mockups, presentations, sketches, back of napkin designs etc')) ?><br><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('NOTE: Please use dropbox or yousendit and send us the link if the attachment is greater than')) ?> <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('25 MB')) ?></strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__(', or mail them separately to design@xyz.net')) ?></span></label>
                        <div class="custom_textfield">
                            <div id="mulitplefileuploader">
                                <div class="ajax-upload-dragdrop input-text" style="vertical-align:top;">
                                    <div class="ajax-file-upload file_upload custom-upload" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; cursor: default;"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Upload')) ?>
                                        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() . 'questionnaire/index/save'; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="Formisimo_clocked_25785" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                                            <input type="file" id="ajax-upload-id-1526544403771" name="myfile[]" accept="*" multiple="" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 0;">
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <span><b><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Drag &amp; Drop Files')) ?></b></span>
                                </div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ajax-file-upload-container"></div>
                            <div id="status"></div>
                            <input id="filesToAttach" type="hidden" name="filesToAttach">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                    <button class="button btn-default btn start-here-btn" title="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit"><span><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span></span></button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'uploadFileJS'], function ($)
{
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var settings = {
            url: "<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() . 'questionnaire/index/save'; ?>",
            method: "POST",
            allowedTypes: "pdf, ppt, pptx,doc, docx, jpg, jpeg, png, gif, xlsx, xlsm, xlsb, xls, xltx, xltm, xlt, csv, xlam, xla, ods, zip, txt",
            maxFileSize: 26214400,
            fileName: "myfile",
            multiple: true,
            onSuccess: function (files, data, xhr)
            {
                var file_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                alert('ok');
                $('<input>').attr({
                    type: 'hidden',
                    name: file_data.original + "[]",
                    value: file_data.modified
                }).appendTo('form');
            },
            onError: function (files, status, errMsg)
            {
                alert('fail');
                $("#status").html(errMsg);
            }
        };
        $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);
    });

});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'mage/mage'], function ($)
{
    var dataForm = $('#questionnaire_form');
    dataForm.mage('validation', {});
});
```

here is requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        JQ1: 'Tatva_Questionnaire/js/jquery-1.11.4-ui',
        icheck: 'Tatva_Questionnaire/js/icheck.min',
        fancybox: 'Tatva_Questionnaire/js/jquery.fancybox',
        JQForm: 'Tatva_Questionnaire/js/jquery.form',
        uploadFileJS: 'Tatva_Questionnaire/js/jquery.uploadfile',
    }
}
```

};

Comment: have you checked console log?

Comment: yes i checked console log validation script is not working, so many reqiure.js error  @kunj

Comment: Ok, please share those errors.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined at Function.metadataRules (VM5836 jquery.validate.js:903)
    at jQuery.fn.init.rules (VM5836 jquery.validate.js:161)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (VM5836 jquery.validate.js:493)
    at VM5730 jquery.js:2769
    at Function.grep (VM5730 jquery.js:465)
    at winnow (VM5730 jquery.js:2767)
    at jQuery.fn.init.filter (VM5730 jquery.js:2835)
    at $.validator.elements (VM5836 jquery.validate.js:487)
    at $.validator.checkForm (VM5836 jquery.validate.js:371)
    at $.validator.form (VM5836 jquery.validate.js:359)

Comment: Please share `uploadFileJS.js`.

Comment: uploadFileJS.js is third party plugin, i am enable to post it as it contain so many code and body is limited to 30000 characters, thankyou @kunj

Comment: Can you share that URL? Please share your `requirejs-config.js`.

Comment: question edited @kunj

Comment: maybe problem occurred because i use nested form @kunj

Comment: yes, I have tried after remove child form but still getting same.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="name" value="<?php
                    if ($name)
                    {
                        echo $name;
                    }
                    ?>" type="text" class="input-text required-entry" tabindex="1">
```

in above code can you try to add `data-validate="{required:true}"` like following and then check?

```
 <input name="name" value="<?php
                        if ($name)
                        {
                            echo $name;
                        }
                        ?>" type="text" class="input-text required-entry" 
data-validate="{required:true}"  tabindex="1" />
```

I've done like above and it's working fine with Default Magento validation.

And keep following code just after ending the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'mage/mage'], function ($)
{
    var dataForm = $('#questionnaire_form');
    dataForm.mage('validation', {});
});
</script>
```

Comment: thankyou for your replay but still not working @Kaushal Suthar

Answer (score 0):

Problem occurred due to nested form, i separate both the form and it work..

```
<form name="questionnaire_form" id="questionnaire_form" action="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() . 'questionnaire/index/sendEmail'; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="std">
    <div class="product-info-block about-content">
        <div class="page-title category-title">
            <h1><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Custom Design Services FORM')) ?></h1>
        </div>
        <p>                
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Help us understand your requirements better. Fill in this short form, or just email your details to')) ?>
            <a href="mailto:design@slideteam.net">design@slideteam.net</a>
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__(', and let us know if we can call you to ask clarifying questions.')) ?>
        </p>
        <div class="user-detail">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('First and Last Name')) ?><em>*</em></label>
                    <input name="name" value="<?php if ($name) { echo $name; } ?>" type="text" class="input-text required-entry" tabindex="1">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('User ID / Email')) ?><em>*</em></label>
                    <input name="email" value="<?php if ($email) { echo $email; } ?>" type="text" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" tabindex="2">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone (optional)')) ?></label>
                    <input name="phone" value="<?php if ($phone) { echo $phone; } ?>" type="text" class="input-text validate-digits" tabindex="3">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="blank-label">&nbsp;</label>
                    <ul class="radio-listing">
                        <li tabindex="4">
                            <input type="radio" class="icheck" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Call me')) ?>" name="call_flag" checked="">
                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Call me')) ?></span>
                        </li>
                        <li tabindex="5">
                            <input type="radio" class="icheck" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Do not call me')) ?>" name="call_flag">
                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Do not call me')) ?></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="user-detail">
            <h4><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Fill to the best of your knowledge - no field is mandatory')) ?></h4>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Number of Slides to be designed')) ?></label>
                    <input name="number_of_slides" value="<?php if ($number_of_slides) { echo $number_of_slides; } ?>" type="text" class="input-text" tabindex="6">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Describe Your Style Requirement')) ?> 
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('1. Stylish and Graphical ')) ?>
                            <em>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" tabindex="-1">?
                                    <span>
                                        <ul class="list">
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Consistent 3-5 Colors throughout')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Text in text boxes with shadows/layers etc')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Greater graphical content')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Example Audience - Company Employees, Team Members,Professors and Students, Prospective Customers')) ?></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </em>
                        </span>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('2. Elegant and Simple ')) ?>
                            <em>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" tabindex="-1">?
                                    <span>
                                        <ul class="list">
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Consistent 2-3 Colors throughout')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Corporate Style')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Convey ideas graphically but to a degree')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Example Audience - Board of Directors, CEOs, CFOs, Investors, Investment Banking, Highly Business Oriented Audience')) ?></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </em>
                        </span>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('3. Informal and Playful ')) ?>
                            <em>
                                <a href="#" class="tooltips" tabindex="-1">?
                                    <span>
                                        <ul class="list">
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Colorful but consistent themes/shades')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Fancy Graphics - visually appealing')) ?></li>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Example Audience - Community gatherings, Schools, Family gatherings and Parties, Churches and Religious gatherings')) ?></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </em>
                        </span>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('4. Combination of the above')) ?> </span>
                    </label>
                    <textarea name="style_option" class="input-text" tabindex="7"><?php if ($style_option) { echo $style_option; } ?></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('URLs or Names of any preferred SlideTeam')) ?> 
                        <a href=""><u><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Templates')) ?></u></a> <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('or')) ?> <a href=""><u><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Diagrams')) ?></u></a><span><a style="color: #393939" href=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Templates are')) ?></a> <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('slide backgrounds')) ?><br><a style="color: #393939" href=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Diagrams are')) ?></a> <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('actual slides')) ?></span>
                    </label>
                    <textarea name="template_or_diagram_details" class="input-text" tabindex="8"><?php if ($template_or_diagram_details) { echo $template_or_diagram_details; } ?></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Description and Flow')) ?><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Notes to the designer. Be as complete and detailed as you can.')) ?></span></label>
                    <textarea class="input-text" name="description" tabindex="9"><?php if ($description) { echo $description; } ?></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="custom_row">
                        <label>
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Upload Files')) ?> <br> <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please upload any mockups, presentations, sketches, back of napkin designs etc')) ?><br><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('NOTE: Please use dropbox or yousendit and send us the link if the attachment is greater than')) ?> <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('25 MB')) ?></strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__(', or mail them separately to design@slideteam.net')) ?></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <input id="filesToAttach" type="hidden" name="filesToAttach">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                    <button class="button btn-default btn start-here-btn" title="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit"><span><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span></span></button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="custom_textfield">
  <div id="mulitplefileuploader">
    <div class="ajax-upload-dragdrop input-text" style="vertical-align:top;">
        <div class="ajax-file-upload file_upload custom-upload" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; cursor: default;"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Upload')) ?>
            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() . 'questionnaire/index/save'; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="Formisimo_clocked_25785" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <input type="file" id="ajax-upload-id-1526544403771" name="myfile[]" accept="*" multiple="" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 0;">
            </form>
        </div>
        <span><b><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Drag &amp; Drop Files')) ?></b></span>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="ajax-file-upload-container"></div>
<div id="status"></div>
```